# I want to sort a list by frequency of values and distinct it c#

Tags: c#, list, distinct, frequency

I have a list of integers, for example

```
List<int> Lst = {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4}
```

I want this list to be

```
Lst = {1,3,2,4}
```

(sorted by frequency of values and distinct so 1 is first and 
3 after and 2 after and then 4
Thanks for the help :D

Im working on a project and I have a list that comes like this and I need to rearrange it

I havent try to make it work with a code yet because I cant think of a way to make it work

I expect the output of the function to be a list that arranged like {1,3,2,4}
Thanks :D

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. This by itself is a legitimate question but unfortunately this is not how SO works. You should first try to write code to solve your problem and show what you have tried.

Comment: Try following :            List<int> Lst = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4 };

            var results = Lst.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { number = x.Key, count = x.Count() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.count).ToList();

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a good question after you try and program it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly easy with Linq's `GroupBy`:

```
var input = new [] {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4};
var output = input.GroupBy(x => x)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();
```

- `GroupBy(x => x)`: Creates a list of 4 groups. Each group has a key which is the number, and values which are the members of the group. So you'll have something like `{ 1: [1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3, 3, 3], 4: [4, 4] }`
- `OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())`: order the groups by the number of items in the group, with the largest group first. So you get `{ 1: [1, 1, 1], 3: [3, 3, 3], 2: [2, 2], 4: [4, 4] }`
- `Select(x => x.Key)`: Take the key from each group, so you get `[1, 3, 2, 4]`
- `ToList()`: turn it all into a list

If there are two groups with equal numbers of items -- in your example, there are three 1's and three 3's -- then this will sort them in the order that they appeared in the input (so, here, the output is `[1, 3, 2, 4]`, because 1 comes before 3 in the input).

This is because of the [ordering behaviour of `GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) (see Remarks):

> The IGrouping objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source.

and the fact that [`OrderByDescending` is stable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderByDescending__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) (again, see the Remarks), so if two items compare equally their order is preserved).

> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements that have the same key.

Comment: (Didn't downvote but:) Why post answers for questions that show no effort in solving the problem first?.... This is not how OP will learn

Comment: and I guess this does not ensure that 1 comes before 3 as OP specified, because both have count 3. Insert a `ThenBy(x = x.Key)` after `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: @RenéVogt `OrderByDescending` is stable, so if the item appeared first in the input, it appears first in the output. That matches the OP's specification - he didn't say that items with equal counts should be ordered numerically? The output of this matches the OP's example output. The ordering of `GroupBy` is likewise specified, so that groups appear in the order that their key first appeared in the input.

Comment: @GiladGreen this is a hard problem if you don't know about `GroupBy` and the stable properties of `OrderByDescending`, so I don't fault him for not having his attempted solution in this question (I mean he could have written some useless rubbish to tick a box, but what's the point in that?). His question was fairly clear, and included example input and output. Attempted solutions are also not required: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284605/1086121

Comment: @canton7 - true but even googling the general problem and coming up with the idea of doing a histogram and then doing stuff is good. I agree code examples are not only what shows effort but question didn't show any effort

Comment: @canton7 +1, I also believe that your answer has all the elements to not only provide a solution for the problem the OP has today but also similar problems other OPs may have in the future